# Will the size of a Solr core on disk grow indefinitely?

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

Optimize de-fragments the index and reduced the size of the index on disk. It does this by reclaiming the space from deleted documents.

[But this is now deprecated](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html) as 'it is horribly inefficient and very rarely justified'.

Is there an alternative method of reclaiming space from deleted documents? the documentation suggests that this is automatically achieved using default settings ([TieredMergePolicy](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TieredMergePolicy.html)). But I have not seen this behaviour in a basic installation (max doc count grows and is not reduced, while numDocs is reduced), does this require configuration?  or is there another more efficient method of reclaiming this disk space now the optimize is deprecated?

Edit: Using solr 4.6.1 and solrj to manage documents. The schema is the same as the default provided with the [4.6.1 download](http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/4.6.1/) with a few extra basic string fields.

Comment: have you run your instance long enough to have any segments merged?

Comment: It's been running for a week and has over 4 million documents, what is the criteria for a merge being performed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling optimize will not necessarely clean your index and reduice size on windows :

**> > Why doesn't my index directory get smaller (immediately) when i delete documents? force a merge? optimize?**

> Because of the "inverted index" data structure, deleting documents
>   only annotates them as deleted for the purpose of searching. The space
>   used by those documents will be reclaimed when the segments they are
>   in are merged.
>
> When segments are merged (either because of the Merge Policy as
>   documents are added, or explicitly because of a forced merge or
>   optimize command) then Solr attempts to delete old segment files, but
>   on some filesystems Notably in Microsoft Windows) it is not possible
>   to delete a file while the file is open for reading (Which is usually
>   true since Solr is still serving requests against the old segments
>   until the new Searcher is ready and has it's caches warmed). When this
>   happens, the older segment files are left on disk, and Solr will
>   re-attempt to delete them later the next time a merge happens.

[solr FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ)

So under windows, I will recommand you to make some changes on the index to see the delete occurs.

So please :

- perform your delete
- commit
- perform put
- commit
- see your index size !:)

**To conclude, as far as I've tested, The Lucene engines will only perform a delete of thoses "deleted docs" when it needs to PUT/POST a doc!**